# Запуск Start Experimental Instance of Visual Studio 2019 с помощью DTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Как запустить Start Experimental Instance of Visual Studio 2019 с помощью DTE?
Достучаться до VS 2019 получается так:

```
var executablePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe");

var vsProcess = Process.Start(executablePath);

var runningObjectDisplayName = $"VisualStudio.DTE.16.0:{vsProcess.Id}";
```

Была неудачная попытка: $"VisualStudio.DTE.16.0Exp:{vsProcess.Id}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено, вдруг кому будет интересно.
Используем аргумент **/rootsuffix Exp.**

```
var executablePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe");
var info = new ProcessStartInfo(executablePath, "/rootsuffix Exp");
var vsProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
var runningObjectDisplayName = $"VisualStudio.DTE.16.0:{vsProcess.Id}";
```